# Solution for Managing Sets of Users

Tags: permissions, user-management

In an org I would like to setup 200+ sets of users which would have a user in charge to control access to his subset of users. He will need to create, edit and assign users to profiles and permission sets.

I have done some research and saw the option of using [Delegated Administrators](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.delegating_user_administration.htm&type=5), but since not all of these users know how to use Salesforce, I would like to know if there's an app on the app exchange that can do this in a user friendly way.

Any information would be appreciated.

Comment: Please see [ask] on how to get the most from the Community. This question does not show any research.

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: If you haven't found anything on the AppExchange or in your web searches, then there probably isn't one.

Comment: an alternative solution is for your org to provision users from your corporate onboarding systems and use the SFDC User Access Policies to automate the assignment of profiles, permission sets, roles, and public groups.  A fully-automated solution